# What is the best number of threads in parallel programs in java?

Tags: multithreading

What is the best number of threads in parallel programs in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoT<= (noc) / (1 - bf)
NoT- Number of threads 
noc- number of cores
Bf - block factor
For best performance
No of cores -1

Comment: This formula ignores the effects of blocking I/O, synchronization, garbage collection and various kinds of memory contention.  It is not predictive for typical Java programs.